# Django SUM 2 Column with Different Condition

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django how to `sum` 2 `column` with different condition, how i try to sum `column` `amount` with condition `trx=2` and `amount` with condition `trx=3`

```
reportusage = (Invoices.objects
                            .annotate(month=ExtractMonth('datetime'))
                            .values('month')
                            .annotate(total=Sum('amount').filter(trx=2) + Sum('amount').filter(trx=3), product=F('tenant'))
                            .order_by())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a filter on the column in annotation, you may try this

```
reportusage = (Invoices.objects
                            .annotate(month=ExtractMonth('datetime'))
                            .values('month')
                            .annotate(total=Sum('amount', filter=Q(trx=3)) + Sum('amount', filter=Q(trx=3)), product=F('tenant'))
                            .order_by())
```